# TIFF to JPEG Conversion Results in a larger image size

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have the following function which takes a `tiff` stored as `blob` from an older database and converts it into `jpeg` and then stores it as a `varbinary(max)` in `sql server`.

```
public byte[] ConvertImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null) return null;
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageData)))
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image))
        {
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
              {
                  bmp.Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                  return outStream.ToArray();
              }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the conversion is resulting in the size of the image being increased by 10 folds or more. Am i doing something incorrectly?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If your TIFF images uses lossy compression, then unless you want ti reduce the quality factor, don't play with it.

Comment: TIFF == Thousand of Incompatible File Formats.  I gave it a shot, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the JPEG compression level:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx

JPEG isn't going to always be better than TIFF, though.  TIFF is a container format that can use all sorts of image compression formats so your image could be compressed using another method already.

Comment: +1: For pointing out that `TIFF` supports more than one compression format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `EncoderParameter` for quality. Try something like:

```
public byte[] ConvertImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null) return null;
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageData)))
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image))
        {
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var ratio = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 50L); //adjust this value for desired compression 
                var codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                codecParams.Param[0] = ratio;
                bmp.Save(outStream, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), codecParams);
                return outStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}

ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            return codec;
    return null;
}
```